# FizzBuzz: It gives me the wrong print statement. What is wrong?

Tags: java

Everybody knows that `FizzBuzz` question that interviewers ask students.

Basically, when you have an incrementor and for each number which is a `divisible of 3` you say `fizz`, for a number `divisible by 5` you say `buzz`, while if it is `divisible by both(3 and 5)` you say `FizzBuzz`, hence the name.

It is a relatively easy problem to solve and I have done it, but I think my solution is a bit clunky. This is it:

```java
int[] numbers = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   numbers[i] = i;
}

for (int i : numbers) {
     if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Fizz");
     } else if(i % 5 == 0) {
         System.out.println("Buzz");
     } else {
         System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
     }
}
```

But the problem is that when the number is divisible by both 3 and 5 it gives me "Fizz" for some reason. Can somebody explain to me, because I'm new to java programming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because the first condition will be `true` not regarding the second one. You should first check if it is divisible by both values, if not, check them separetely.

Comment: That's a common error with FizzBuzz. If a number is divisible by 5 and 3, what does the first condition result in?

Comment: @deHaar giving away the solution like this doesn't help much when someone's learning, IMHO

Comment: Also, this prints fizzbuzz for all numbers divisible by neither 3 nor 5, e.g. 1, 2.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah, kinda right... I did't want to provide code, just the facts. If that's too much, I will have to write less comments.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm not convinced there is that much you can say without effectively "giving away" the solution.

Comment: @AndyTurner, still IMHO, there's a difference between my comment and deHaar's one. But of course that's just my opinion. There's a reason I'm not downvoting the answers giving the full solution :) . But I still think OP would be better helped in the long term by a nudge in the right direction than by an outright solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the FizzBuzz using loops in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652324/how-to-create-the-fizzbuzz-using-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the order of your if statements. Lets take a look at the number 15, which is the first number divisible by both 3 and 5. Because of the order in which you have your if statements, the first statement that is checked is

```
if ( 15 % 3 == 0)
```

The result of the operation is indeed equal to 0, as 15 is divisible by 3 and so "Fizz" is printed and your `else` is ignored.

Think about how you should structure the order of your if statements and which additional condition should you introduce to catch the specific case of being divisible by both `i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the `if` statement and your number is 15 for exemple, you enter the first `if` statement and.. prints "Fizz" as you stated, because `15 % 3 == 0` returns `true`. Then it ignores the `else`.

You want the first `if` to be

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
  System.out.println("FizzBuzz");*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       numbers[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i : numbers) {
         if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
         } else if(i % 5 == 0) {
             System.out.println("Buzz");
         } else if (i % 3 == 0){
             System.out.println("Fizz");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Frian, you should add a bit of explanation while you're at it.